# Initialization of schema during oracle initialization using docker file

Tags: java, oracle, docker, dockerfile

I am doing some POC using *Docker*, to set up a working environment using *Tomcat* and *Oracle* XE database. I am able to create an *Oracle* XE image using the dockerfile from the url https://hub.docker.com/r/sath89/oracle-xe-11g/~/dockerfile/, but my requirement is initializing a schema during oracle startup using *Docker* agnostic approach.

I have tried the below sh file to access a ***.sql*** file which contains an insert script as of now (instead of a schema creation).

Below is my *dbsetup.sh* file:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
echo "Starting file execution"
date
sqlplus -s system/oracle  << EOF >> D:/java/sql@DbScripts.sql
EOF
echo "Completed execution"
echo "Date is : 'date'"
```

The *DbScripts.sql*:

```sql
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES(75340,'PRODUCT2','CATEGORY2');
```

Comment: You can run a script from Docker once oracle is running to create the schema, in the same way that the Dockerfile calls `oracle-install.sh`... So you can build your own Dockerfile which extends the one you linked which does the schema creation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I did not clearly get your point, could you please explain me the approach which you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/18.4.0).  Build the docker image using:

```
bash ./buildDockerImage.sh -v 18.4.0 -i -x
```

Start the container; then, you can execute your script with this:

```
docker exec -t --user oracle <container_id> bash -c "echo exit | sqlplus system/oracle @<path_to_your_script>DbScripts.sql"
```

Note, for this to work, you will need to mount the volume to the location of your scripts.